# Translating a CURL call to Python script

Tags: python, curl

Finding it problematic to convert a simple CURL request in Windows to a Python script

The **CURL command** is

`curl -X POST -d "{\"query\": \"NEW YORK\"}" http://192.168.0.106:8080/parser`

I get the **output**:

```
[{"label":"state","value":"new york"}]
```

The **Python script** is

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = 'http://192.168.0.106:8080/parser' # Set destination URL here
post_fields = {"query": "NEW YORK"}     # Set POST fields here

request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
print(json)
```

The output is []. Nothing basically.

Comment: Does the sample query you create in your cURL request do the same?

Comment: Sorry it was New York in both the cases. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `requests`:

```
import requests

data = '{"query": "NEW YORK"}'

response = requests.post('http://192.168.0.106:8080/parser', data=data)
```

Full documentation can be found at [Requests: HTTP for Humans](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell why wasn't my program not working?

Comment: @ZaidKhan Not really sure. I don't really use `urllib`. I just translated your curl POST request to `requests`, which is the easiest way to do it in python.